# Is there a backstory to (the sci-fi portion of) Carrera's Strax toy line?

Tags: story-identification, toys

The *Strax* toyline by [Carrera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrera_(slot_car_brand))<sup>1</sup> (or at least a part of it) used to feature futuristic cars in a somewhat otherworldly setting with purple rocks and high-tech-looking buildings. (As an example for what I mean, look at <s>the first and the third of the larger pictures in [this blogpost](http://blog.achtziger-forum.de/2015/09/21/carrera-strax-1985/) (text only in German, but it's irrelevant to this question)</s>, the picture in [this blogpost](https://kennstdunoch.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/kennt-ihr-noch-11/), the profile picture of [this Facebook account](https://www.facebook.com/pg/Carrera-STRAX-122129377895355/posts/), or the photos in [this promotional booklet](http://www.he-man.org/publishing/item.php?id=1942&image=10381).)

[image: *Strax* toyline by Carrera]

**Was there any kind of an official backstory for this setting and the products presented in it?** (I mean something that would (irrespective of whether or not users of the toys would invariably stick to it) answer questions like *why are they driving around on that world? Do they belong to different factions? What is the significance of the rocks with faces?* etc.)

---

<sup>1</sup>: It is surprisingly hard to add a link for this. The toy line seems to have been discontinued, so Carrera's official website does not mention it any more. There are various Ebay auctions of Strax toys, but some have already expired and have disappeared (only still visible in Google Images), and the same will happen to others, as well. Hence, stable links to images of these toys seem rare, although Google Images finds a fair amount.

Comment: Perhaps a Wayback Machine link will have it?

Comment: The panels from this (german) promotional booklet would suggest that the backstory was just a mish-mash of tropes; http://www.he-man.org/publishing/item.php?id=1942&image=10386

Comment: @Valorum: Good find. It's true that the promotional booklet contains no real backstory to speak of (the texts are more like descriptions of what children could do with the toys, rather than an in-universe view on what's happening there). It's interesting how some of the cars appear to have names, though. I'll add the link as an additional example of the promotional images to the question. Thank you.